# How to synchronise in-app subscriptions with android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have developed an android and iOS application. In that, I have used in-app purchase subscription. Now I am struggling how to sync the subscription between two platforms.

Suppose I have purchased paid 3-months subscription from Android and now I want to upgrade my subscription to Premium 3-months from iOS. How I can do that because the upgrade subscription is only possible "android to android" and "iOS to iOS" not cross-platform.

Also, I have purchased a subscription from android now I want to cancel it from ios. How I can do it. I know this is not possible but If is there any alternative than please suggest.

Comment: You'll need to have one central database server that keeps membership status of users, when a user completes purchase on Android or iOS, you will need to send the transaction number to the server, server will verify the transaction number and grant premium status.

Comment: do it on a web?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir  I have already managed this but the only question is upgrade subscription because if the user has an ongoing subscription from android and now he uses iPhone to upgrade subscription. how android and iOS cross-platform works.

Comment: @ChetanPatil I don't think you'll be able to do that unless you handle it manually by giving a free subscription to user on iOS if he has one on Android.
You may have to use another subscription service instead of the ones provided by app stores.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir You mean to say we need to use third party payment gateway for subscription

Comment: Not necessarily a payment gateway, you can use app store and playstore payment gateway for 'purchase' but manage the subscription yourself.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir how can we manage subscription at our end if the user has subscribed to any subscription on android. we will only say user from iOS to upgrade your subscription from android Or He needs to cancel old subscription from play store and get upgraded fresh subscription from iOS. Please correct if i am wrong

Comment: @ChetanPatil what is your scenario? Do you want the subscription to be shared? Like if you subscribe on Android and goto iOS user will have premium there as well? Or do you want to cancel on 1 before moving to other?

Comment: @ChetanPatil Please give a detailed use case scenario so I can give you specific points rather than general ideas.

Comment: @ZohaibAmir 
1. Subscription to be shared from android to iOS that I have already mange using real-time developer notification.
2. If the user has get one subscription from android and he should able to upgrade it from iOS. here I am stuck because android in-app-billing only allows us to upgarde subscription from androiid it self not from ios

Comment: @ChetanPatil If user wants to renew subscription, you want him/her to do so from iOS even if he subscribed from Android previously, correct?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir renewal is not a problem only subscription plan upgrade is an issue. If you have any solution to upgrade  play store subscription from ios or wise verse please let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196918/discussion-between-chetan-patil-and-zohaib-amir).

Answer (score 5):

It's impossible to cancel/upgrade an iOS subscription from anywhere else, so for these situations I always like to look at the big subscription apps to see how they handle it. And it seems like your best bet is to include some text to inform the user that they need to manage their subscription from another platform.

Looking at the HBO Now app they show me:

> "Your subscription is being billed and managed through your iTunes
>   account"